# Getting started with Rails - post path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in rails, and I decided to start learning from the Getting Started with Rails (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

In the chapter "Updating 5:12 Posts" after I include the "show" link ( <% = link_to 'Show', post_path%> ), an error came up. (image)

[image: SS]

Could anyone help me, is there a syntax error?

Thank you

Comment: can u post your routes file here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
post_path(post)
```

Do you have a resource route set up for posts?

Comment: Just set posts_path instead of post_path and it worked. I understand now how this wor. Thanks!